# ¿Cómo solucionar el error Uncaught ReferenceError?

Tags: php, javascript

Sucede que necesito buscar un dato para que muestre, en un gráfico, los registros que tengan de ese nombre. Cuando llamo a la variable no me quiere mostrar ningún dato y además me surgió este tipo de error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: s2 is not defined at window.onload

El punto es que los datos existen ya que utilicé como prueba una constante 
(que está comentada), pero no sé qué hacer para solucionarlo.

**Código**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

        var id = <?php echo $_GET['txtBuscarNombreSensor'];?>;
        //var id= 's2';

        var dataLength = 0;
        var data = [];

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", {
            title: {
                text: "Graficos"
            },
            axisX: {
                title: "Fecha",
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Sensores",
            },
            data: [{ type: "line", dataPoints: data }],
        });


        $.getJSON("data.php?f=graficoBuscarSensor&txtBuscarNombreSensor=" + id, function (result) {
            dataLength = result.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                data.push({
                    x: new Date(result[i].FECHA),
                    y: parseInt(result[i].Cantidad)
                });
            }
            ;
            chart.render();
        });

    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Prueba con "windows.ready" en lugar de "window.onload" . ¿El valor "s2" es de la gráfica o de qué elemento de tu página exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error esta en la forma en la que estas asignandole el valor a la variable `id`. Estas esperando que cuando php renderice tu javascript, este asigne un string a la variable `id` de la siguiente manera: `var id = 's2'`, sin embargo, cuando el código renderiza, lo que obtienes es `var = s2`; por lo tanto la solución esta en concatenar lo que renderiza php dentro de comillas:

```
var id = "<?php echo $_GET['txtBuscarNombreSensor'];?>";
```

Tambien, si mal no recuerdo creo que puedes usar `<?=$_GET['property']?>` para ahorrarte el `<?php echo`